# Should I rely on dirty checking?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I use Grails, which uses Hibernate for persistance under the hood.

My questiion is if it is a good practice to rely on dirty checking or should I always explicitly call `save()` method on entities every time I change them?

**UPD:** This question is NOT about dirty checking mechanics, this question is about it's reliability. That is, when I want to update an entity:

```
def user = User.get(1)
user.name = 'new name'
user.save()  //optional
```

I can ommit the last line, Hibernate will detect the change by itself and persist it, but can I be 100% sure?

Do you always explicitly call save() after updates in your projects?

Comment: It sounds like you need to read up on what save means when you're using Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

All entity insertions&updations  were saved using `Session.save()` &   `Session.saveOrUpdate()`

Until and unless you fire the save with in the `session` ,They are not not going to be save in `DataBase` anymore .

Once you saved the object and still you are modifying  the object Hibernate's `Dirty checking` will come into the picture .

In `dirty checking`, `hibernate` automatically detects whether  an object is modified (or) not and need to be updated. As long as the object is in `persistent state` i.e., 
bound to a particular Session(org.hibernate.Session). Hibernate monitors any changes to the objects and executes sql.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some researches on dirty check

1. Fush session will reset origin state

   def patient = Patient.get(id)

   patient.name = 'xxx'

   patient.isDirty() --> true

   patient.save()

   patient.isDirty() --> true

   patient.save(flush:true)

   patient.isDirty() --> false !! flush will reset the origin state
2. Hql query will also reset origin sate

   def patient = Patient.get(id)

   patient.name = 'xxx'

   patient.isDirty() --> true

   Patient.findByXXXX()

   patient.isDirty() --> false

Comment: [grails-issue-not-processed-by-flush-root-causes](http://naleid.com/blog/2010/11/21/grails-issue-not-processed-by-flush-root-causes)